# Cannot copy the public key to remote-host using cat

Tags: ssh, centos

Im trying to setup the passwordless SSh Login like the one stated [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/25/how-to-set-up-a-password-less-ssh-login/)

I was able to generate the SSH Key Successfully

> ssh-keygen

But when I'm doing this

> cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat >>
>   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'

it gave me this error

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal
>
> ssh : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxcat >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh
>   user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat >>> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'

I tried to setup [passwordless SSH](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) without getting this kind of error but its not working  because it is still asking for password. And according to the author of this article, SSH-copy-id has 3 issues which most probably the reason why It still asking for password.

Any ideas?

Note: machines are running on CentOS

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh -t -t user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

`-t -t` option to force pseudo-tty allocation even if stdin isn't a terminal.

Comment: it was asking for the password, when I typed in the password, it says "tcgetattr: Invalid argument"

Comment: @srhsnl, you can check xxxx:~/.ssh/authorized_keys, is your id_dsa.pub already there ? I think already there.

`ssh -t` is meant to be used for interactive use, so when the input is from a terminal. Here, ssh stdin is not a terminal but from pipe, so tcgetattr fails on it. Don't worry about this !